# Fibonacci Sequence based question slightly changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, fibonacci

I was recently given this question in one of my interview which I ofcourse, failed.

[image: Question]

I just want to know how this will be solved. **The code I tried to use was this:**

```
def gibonacci(n, x, y):
    # Base case
    if n == 0:
        return x
    elif n == 1:
        return y
    else:
        sequence = [x, y]
        for i in range(2, n):
            next_term = sequence[i-1] - sequence[i-2]
            sequence.append(next_term)
        return sequence[-1]
```

Any help, even just the logical help will be enough. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the point of the interview was to implement an iterative function. It was probably to see who can see the pattern in the result.

Comment: You're off by one: `for i in range(2, n+1):`

Comment: To say my point otherwise: the "slight" change in Fibonacci (and more precisely, - instead of +) is not "slight" at all. That changes everything to the dynamic of the sequence. And I am pretty sure the test is designed to see who can spot it, and the affirmation that gibonnaci is a "similar" sequence, was the trap here. It may be similar in writing, but not at all in behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was a bit vague for me, but try the following code, it might help you.

Try this:

```
def gibonacci(n,x,y):   
    if n == 0:
        return x

    elif n == 1:
        return y

    else:
        for i in range(1, n):
            c = y - x
            x = y
            y = c

        return y

print(gibonacci(2,0,1))
```

Comment: That is an overly expansive way to compute it. I mean, my own 1st solution would probably have been that one. But then, I would trace the result on some examples, and see that there are possible optimization. I am pretty sure the whole point of the interview was to test who can spot the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, I am pretty sure the interview was made to check who can think to the problem before thinking to the solution.

See what your sequence is
g₀ = x
g₁ = y
g₂ = y-x
g₃ = y-x - y = -x
g₄ = -x - (y-x) = -y
g₅ = -y - (-x) = x-y
g₆ = x-y - (-y) = x
g₇ = x - (x-y) = y
...

Once you got 2 repeating items in the sequence, you can't do anything other than repeat the rest. Said otherwise, gₙ₊₆=gₙ forever. So, the pattern is always the same length-6 cycle: x, y, y-x, -x, -y, x-y

Hence the faster solution, without any iteration

```py
def gibonacci(n, x, y):
   if n%3==0:
       r=x
   elif n%3==1:
       r=y
   else:
       r=y-x
   if (n//3)%2:
       return -r
   else: 
       return r
```

Works in O(1) (contrarily to iterative methods that are O(n)).

More "raw" (faster, but less explicit with the logic. Anyway, all O(1)) variants can exist. Such as this one-liner:

```py
def gibonacci(n, x, y):
    return [x,y,y-x,-x,-y,x-y][n%6]
```

I am not the interviewer. So I can't presume what was they looking for. But my instinct is that the accepted answer would have failed the interview, even if it works, and that the expected answer was in the line of this one.

### Edit: timing consideration

Sorry to go back on this; but because of a recent notification — thanks to an upvoter :D — I saw this question again, and notice something I haven't paid enough attention to in the first place. The question contains a trappy assertion that you can assume that n<10⁹.
I said "trappy" (I mean, it is made to deceive) because it looks like it means "don't worry, n is not too big". But 10⁹ is big, and in reality that means "beware, n could be up to 10⁹".

So out of curiosity, on my (rather old, sure, but still, a modern machine wouldn't be 10 times faster, and even then, I still get my point), I timed the accepted answer with n=10⁹. On my computer it takes 78 seconds.

Mine, of course (no iteration) takes 370 ns. That is 200 million times faster. We are not talking mere optimization here. Such difference is the difference between "fast" and "practically impossible".

So that remark (n<10⁹) in the statement is one extra proof that you were expected to never ever use an iterative computation.